# CI_VSTS publish different web Artifact for each project in single solution

Tags: azure-devops, publish

I have a CI pipeline(VSTS) in which I am able to build whole solution which has two website projects in it in a single artifact. What I want to do it build whole solution and then create publish artifact for each project. 
e.g.
One artifact for Project_website1
One artifact for Project_website2
thanks. I tried similar topic in StackOverflow but didnt work for me

Comment: Have you get the answer which helps you solve the problem? If yes, you can mark the answer by clicking √ symbol on the left of the answer. And it will also benefit other members who meet similar questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I have done
As I am using my own agent
So the web projects are published in agent’s each project published directory.
That is directory a.

Solution:
All i did was after builidng the whole solution once vsts put all website in publish directory a.
I wrote powershell script to get each file for project and put it under subdirectory in published folder a.

E.g
Publish folder a will look like this after building solution
Website1.......xml
Website1.......zip
.
.
.
Website2........xml
Website2........zip
.
.
.

Etc 
When solution is build the files will be in above folder togeter.

In order to build artifact for each project i wrote powershell script to put each project file in sub directory
E.g
a\website1
Website1.......xml
Website1.......zip

a\website2
Website2.......xml
Website2.......zip

Etc and so on

After that select each publish artifact for each directory and you can have artifact for each project.
Thanks

Comment: Could you elaborate more your answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use two publish artifacts tasks and may be copy files multiple tasks to achieve any number of artifact in VSTS build. For example, say you have your current artifacts for a single project, comprising of _PublishedWebsites\MVS5WebApp (XCopy deployable website) and _PublishedWebsites\MVS5WebApp_Package (web deploy package).
[image]
 If you want to separate these two, into two artifacts, you can use two Publish Artifact tasks as shown below, each one specifying exact path to publish (this path does not support wildcards, you just have to specify the folder you need to publish).

[image]
[image]

Result would be two artifacts
[image]

You can get more idea from the post [here](http://chamindac.blogspot.com/2017/12/creating-multiple-artifacts-in-single.html?_sm_au_=iVVKG65L4LKpR8qq).
Also [this post](http://chamindac.blogspot.com/2016/07/multiple-build-artifactstfs-2015vsts.html?_sm_au_=iVVKG65L4LKpR8qq) might be useful for you to understand more possibilities.

Comment: [error]Publishing build artifacts failed with an error: Not found PathtoPublish: D:\AgentPath\website\aspweb

Comment: Publish Build artifact => Path to publish=>  $(build.stagingdirectory)\website\aspweb

Comment: How it will know which project to publish on "$(build.stagingdirectory)\website\aspweb"

Comment: Visual Studio Build => MSBuild Arguments
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"

Answer (score 0):

To publish the two websites projects’ artifacts separately, you just need to use **two VS build tasks and two Publish Build Artifacts tasks** to build and publish the two websites separately.

[image]

Such as the first VS build task and Publish Build Artifacts task are for website1, and the second VS build task and Publish Build Artifacts task are for website2. The detail configurations for each task as below:

- VS build task for website1 (store the package for website1 in `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\web1`):

  [image]
- Publish Build Artifacts for website1 (publish website1’s artifacts from `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\web1` to artifact `web1`):

  [image]
- VS build for website2 (store the package for website2 in `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\web2`):

  [image]
- Publish Build Artifacts for website2  (publish website2’s artifacts from `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\web2` to `web2`):

  [image]

Then you can get build artifacts for the two projects separately:

[image]

Comment: You can even do in single build step. the two as long as the two website names are different they will be put on different folders in the package location. it should e a matter of looking at the log and use the correct path to publish in publish artifacts task.